# Logstash with fluent input codec not working

Tags: docker, logstash, jruby, fluentd

I have been using logstash with gelf already and wanted to check out fluent input (mainly due to TCP based docker log-driver for fluent as opposed to UDP only gelf). My configuration for testing is this:

```
input {
  gelf {
    port => 12345
  }
  tcp {
    codec => fluent
    port => 23456
  }
}

filter {
}

output {
  stdout { codec => rubydebug { metadata => true } }
}
```

**I can send gelf logs** using:

```
docker run -it \
           --log-driver gelf \
           --log-opt gelf-address=udp://localhost:12345 \
           --log-opt tag=gelf-test \
        ubuntu:16.04 /bin/bash -c 'echo $(date -u +"%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ") Hello gelf'
```

However the **fluent version does not work**:

```
docker run -it \
           --log-driver fluentd \
           --log-opt fluentd-address=localhost:23456 \
           --log-opt tag=fluent-test \
        ubuntu:16.04 /bin/bash -c 'echo $(date -u +"%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ") Hello fluent'
```

I can verify that logstash is receiving input:

```
echo 'Hello TCP' | nc localhost 23456
```

> An error occurred. Closing connection {:client=>"172.17.0.1:42012", :exception=>#, :backtrace=>["org/jruby/RubyTime.java:1073:in `at'", "/opt/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/logstash-core-event-2.4.0-java/lib/logstash/timestamp.rb:32:in`at'", "/opt/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/logstash-codec-fluent-2.0.4-java/lib/logstash/codecs/fluent.rb:41:in `decode'", "org/msgpack/jruby/MessagePackLibrary.java:195:in`each'", "/opt/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/logstash-codec-fluent-2.0.4-java/lib/logstash/codecs/fluent.rb:40:in `decode'", "/opt/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/logstash-input-tcp-3.0.6/lib/logstash/inputs/tcp.rb:153:in`handle_socket'", "/opt/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/logstash-input-tcp-3.0.6/lib/logstash/inputs/tcp.rb:143:in `server_connection_thread'"], :level=>:error}

I also **disabled the fluent codec** and sent fluent logs and logstash properly errors there as well and parses the fluent msgpack as `message` field of a regular TCP event as expected.

> Received an event that has a different character encoding than you
>   configured.
>   {:text=>"\x94\xABfluent-test\xD2X¢鄣log\xD9\\"2017-03-10T12:58:17Z
>   Hello
>   fluent\r\xACcontainer_id\xD9@9cbd13eb83a02a1a4d4f83ff063d4e40b4419b7dcbcef960e4689495caa5c132\xAEcontainer_name\xAF/ecstatic_kilby\xA6source\xA6stdout\xC0",
>   :expected_charset=>"UTF-8", :level=>:warn}

```
{
       "message" => "\\x94\\xABfluent-test\\xD2X¢鄣log\\xD9\\\"2017-03-10T12:58:17Z Hello fluent\\r\\xACcontainer_id\\xD9@9cbd13eb83a02a1a4d4f83ff063d4e40b4419b7dcbcef960e4689495caa5c132\\xAEcontainer_name\\xAF/ecstatic_kilby\\xA6source\\xA6stdout\\xC0",
      "@version" => "1",
    "@timestamp" => "2017-03-10T12:58:18.069Z",
          "host" => "172.17.0.1",
          "port" => 42016
}
```

I have no other ideas, has anybody run into this issue or have any ideas on how to debug further?

Answer (score 0):

would you please try a Fluentd instance ?, on that way would be easier to determinate where the issue is. Doing a quick view looks like Logstash Fluent codec is not working properly.

Comment: Fluentd as receiver works just fine so I don't think this is an issue on the docker log-driver side. I also tried using a fluentd with fluentd-output-gelf plugin as a forwarder to logstash-gelf and that works fine as well.

As far as I can tell, the issue is somewhere between logstash fluentd codec and pipeline.

Comment: my fluentd receives and parses events from docker just fine as well.  it seems to me theres something at the logstash entry point that has gone astray.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately you can't send messages from fluentd directly to logstash using the existing plugins (it's a shame really).

If you wish to do so, use this [open-source plugin](https://github.com/loomltd/fluent-plugin-loomsystems) which sends the data directly to logstash tcp input (no need for fluentd codec) and also support sending data via secured SSL/TLS protocol.

Seen on this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46264096/3142017).